# Show that F(A−B) is not necessarily a subset of F(A)−F(B).

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $U = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12\}$, and $f$ be a function from $U$ into $U$.

Finally, let $F : P(U) \to P(U)$ be the function defined by

$$F(X) = \{f(x) | x \in X\}$$

For instance, if $f(x) = 13 − x$, and $X = ${1, 3, 4, 7}, then $$F(X) = \{f(1), f(3), f(4), f(7)\} = \{12, 10, 9, 6\}$$

Show that $F(A−B)$ is not necessarily a subset of $F(A)−F(B)$.

---

I am having trouble showing an example.
Let's say:

$A = \{1,3\} , B = \{2,3\}$

$F(A) = \{f(1),f(2)\} = \{12,11\}$

$F(B) =\{f(2),f(3)\} = \{11,10\}$

Now, $F(A-B) = \{12,10\}$

$F(A)-F(B) = \{12\}$.

Hence, $\{12,10\} \nsubseteq \{12\}$ <-- hmm..

By definition if $A \nsubseteq B$, there exist an $x \in A$ such that $x \notin B$. From my example, we have $x=10 \in A $ but $\notin B$. Is that sufficient?

---

I'm confused between the difference of $F(A-B)$ and $F(A)-F(B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample is correct, with the caveat that $10 \in F(A)$, not $A$.

---

The difference between $F(A - B)$ and $F(A) - F(B)$ can be stated in words as "take the image of A without B" versus "take the image of A without the image of B." The order is different: We either take fewer inputs at the start, or take away duplicated outputs at the end.

So for example, suppose that $A = \{x\}$, $B = \{y\}$ with $x \ne y$, but $f(x) = f(y)$. Then

$$F(A - B) = F(\{x\} - \{y\}) = F(\{x\}) = \{f(x)\}$$

On the other hand,

$$F(A) - F(B) = F(\{x\}) - F(\{y\}) = \{f(x)\} - \{f(y)\} = \emptyset$$
since $f(x) = f(y)$.